# Why is time limit exceeded for my solution to Aggressive Cows on SPOJ?

Tags: java, binary-search

**Here is the Aggressive Cows Problem on SPOJ:**

Farmer John has built a new long barn, with N (2 <= N <= 100,000) stalls. The stalls are located along a straight line at positions x1,...,xN (0 <= xi <= 1,000,000,000).

His C (2 <= C <= N) cows don't like this barn layout and become aggressive towards each other once put into a stall. To prevent the cows from hurting each other, FJ wants to assign the cows to the stalls, such that the minimum distance between any two of them is as large as possible. What is the largest minimum distance?

Input

t – the number of test cases, then t test cases follows.

- Line 1: Two space-separated integers: N and C
- Lines 2..N+1: Line i+1 contains an integer stall location, xi

Output

For each test case output one integer: the largest minimum distance.

Example

Input:

1
5 3
1
2
8
4
9
Output:

3
Output details:

FJ can put his 3 cows in the stalls at positions 1, 4 and 8,
resulting in a minimum distance of 3.

**Here is my solution:**

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Cows {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan= new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in));
        int testCases= scan.nextInt();
        for (int i= 0; i < testCases; i++ ) {
            int numStalls= scan.nextInt();
            int numCows= scan.nextInt();
            int[] stalls= new int[numStalls];
            for (int j= 0; j < numStalls; j++ ) {
                stalls[j]= scan.nextInt();
            }
            int largestMin= largestMinDist(numStalls, numCows, stalls);
            System.out.println(largestMin);
        }
        scan.close();
    }

    public static int largestMinDist(int numStalls, int numCows, int[] stalls) {
        Arrays.sort(stalls);
        int low= 0;
        int high= stalls[numStalls - 1];
        int max= -1;
        while (low < high) {
            int mid= (low + high) / 2;
            int pivot= 0;
            int cows= 1;
            for (int i= 1; i < numStalls; i++ ) {
                if (stalls[i] - stalls[pivot] >= mid) {
                    cows++ ;
                    pivot= i;
                }
            }
            if (cows >= numCows) {
                if (mid > max) max= mid;
                low= low + 1;

            } else {
                high= mid;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```

I have several test cases that all pass, including the one given in the example. I'm also using binary search, which I thought would be pretty efficient. However, when I submit my solution, it says time limit exceeded. What is causing this?

Comment: you are using nested loops. Those are slow, concerning the amount of times they need to loop over everything. There are a few ways you could speed up your code. Have you ever tried Streams?

Comment: I have not tried Streams. Is it possible that there is something slow/wrong with my Scanner code? I looked up the solution, and it is very similar to mine, with nested loops and all. I even modified my code a bit to make it even more similar to the solution, but I still get time limit exceeded. The only difference I see is the Scanner part.

Comment: Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); should be enough?